# Does f# programming language have pointers like c++ or pascal(reference pointers)?

Tags: pointers, f#

Doing representation for my computer class project and I need information about pointers in f# language. Do they exist even? Was reading an f# book, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can work with pointers using `fixed` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fixed), though you shouldn't need to do this often. Reference types have some similarities with pointers. What exactly do you need?

Comment: I just need to talk about data structure type that is the closes to pointers, but I have found delegates,referenced and then smth with byref and so on. Just looking for the closest data type that would be  like pointer because in the book there is no section which would be about pointers.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that what you are looking for are the equivalent of pointers to objects? That would be reference types (which most user-defined types are by default, unless they specify they want to have a value type)

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot ,man! That is what I was looking for

Comment: Just for the record, there is also a NativePtr module that allows for operations on unmanaged pointers, as I understand.
https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-nativeinterop-nativeptrmodule.html

Comment: What you are looking for is `byrefs` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/byrefs and `reference cells` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/reference-cells and unmanaged pointers.